# В iPhone 5 не происходит масштабирование элемента input-file по font-size

Tags: html, iphone

В броузерах Safari и Chrome (другие не проверял) на iPhpone 5 при установке `font-size` в css-файле:

```
* {
    font-size : 48px;
  }
```

масштабируются все элементы формы, кроме input-file.

На IE, Chrome и FireFox на PC все отрабатывает штатно и на iPhone 6 - тоже штатно.

На других не пробовал.

Это такая фича конкретно iPhone 5?

Answer (score 1):

Увел input-file в hidden и сделал его активацию через подставную кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

```
input {font-size: 48px;}
```

должно помочь. В Safari для элементов форм прописано много собственных стилей.

Comment: Не помогло :-(  Мне кажется глюк скорее системный - в Crome тоже самое